# Unable to install mysql-server in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apt

I am unable to install mysql-server on my ubuntu 9.10 server machine.
When using apt-get install mysql-server the output is :

```
# apt-get install mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.37-1ubuntu5.4) ...
* Stopping MySQL database server 
    Mysqld    [ OK ]
* Starting MySQL database server 
mysqld [fail]

invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:

mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.1; however:
Package mysql-server-5.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.1
mysql-server  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I cant find a satisfactory solution to this problem anywhere.
Many sites tell to reinstall it but its not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you..

Comment: Have tried using aptitude?  aptitude install mysql-server-5.1

Comment: yeah..tried that as well, same error.

Comment: Had very similar symptoms installing mysql-server, when port 3306 was taken by an SSH tunnel. Took a while to notice, wouldn't expect anything like that to break the package install ...

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server
apt-get purge mysql-common
rm -rf /var/log/mysql
rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql
# and then:
apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

Although it will also remove all dependencies on mysql.

And it will also delete existing databases, backup first!

[Source](http://www.pkshiu.com/loft/archive/2011/12/mysql-installation-on-ubuntu-failed).

Comment: +1 Worked fine for me too!

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and MySQL 5.5.34.

Comment: +1 worked for me too. I had tried apt-get purge mysql-server but not apt-get purge mysql-common and was not working. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me as well

Comment: WARNING: this delete all your databases, backup first!

Comment: It works, thank. When it doesn't work, I don't know why it doesn't work. When it works, I don't know why it works either.

Comment: I get : Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: works for me! just used 'sudo' before each command to run as root

Answer (score 5):

A few suggestions:

- The ever obvious, make sure you are
  running as root.
- Try doing **apt-get remove mysql**.
- Then try doing an **apt-get purge**  (you might need **apt-get purge mysql**, sometimes aptitude can be picky).
- Always check your logs.  They will most likely hold the answer for almost everything.
- Also, try doing an **apt-get clear cache** and **apt-get clean**.  Then try installing again.

Or try this solution I found on google:

> The mysql-server-5.1 package tries to start MySQL after the package is installed, which fails. The first thing you need to do is finish the installation process cleanly. There are several ways to do this:
>
> either fix your MySQL configuration, check that /etc/init.d/mysql-server works, and launch dpkg --configure -a to finish the installation process ;
> or edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.1.postinst and remove the part where it starts the server (probably calling /etc/init.d/mysql-server start or so), then launch dpkg --configure -a to finish the installation process and then fix your configuration.

Comment: Agree with the advice to purge the install & retry

Comment: that dint work!!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL failed to start. The reason this occurred should be logged in /var/log/mysql.log (or is it still /var/lib/mysql/.err?). Can you paste the output from there, and maybe we can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: /var/log/mysql.err and /var/log/mysql.log  both files are empty.

Comment: Following is the output of /usr/local/mysql/clc.err file.clc is hostname
20:50:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
110402 20:50:31 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/clc.lower-test
110402 20:50:31 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/clc.lower-test
110402 20:50:31 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user exists!

110402 20:50:31 [ERROR] Aborting

110402 20:50:31 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

110402 20:50:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/clc.pid ended

Comment: Maybe 1) mysql user does not exist, or 2) /var/lib/mysql is not owned by mysql user? If 2), remember to chown -R.

Comment: this is /etc/passwd file entry: 'mysql:x:118:128:MySQL Server,,,:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/false' . I have already done **chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql** ..

Comment: This is the output of : apt-get purge mysql-server
` * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                              * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                           [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) ` 
_I cant understand why is it starting the mysql-server service when i am removing it._

Comment: is there anything in /var/log/messages?  also, I edited my original answer to include a new, possible solution to your problem.

Comment: @lilott8 .. Nothing about msyql-server in /var/log/messages .. I am going through the link given by you.

Answer (score 1):

Open a different console, enter `ps aux | grep mys`

And kill anything that looks like this:

```
egrep -qi ... /etc/mysql/
```

This should allow the installation to complete.