# Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql5.6

I had an issue installing MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 15.10. Basically loading the db server failed for the mentioned reason.

```
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To overcome this I had to combine the solutions mentioned in the following two posts:

[upgrade-mysql-server-issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292865/upgrade-mysql-server-issue)

[unable-to-install-mysql-server-in-ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/254629/unable-to-install-mysql-server-in-ubuntu/254634)

See also related:

[package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697805/package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet/697806#697806)

**Solution**

*IMPORTANT:* This process will destroy all existing databases as [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) correctly notes. Make sure that you have backups before you start!

Clean out the old mysql installation:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Prepare re-installation of mysql:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Resinstall mysql:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

Enjoy! PS: Doing it without the rm commands did not work!

Comment: Keep in mind that this process will **destroy any existing databases**! Be sure you have a database dump that you can reload later.

Comment: Indeed, this was on a fresh vitual machine so I had not to worry about this. Thanks for this valuable comment which I will add to the solution.